# Laravel Mix - Including/loading JavaScript files sequences issue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, laravel-mix

I am new to Laravel mix and I am trying to port a current app to Laravel. My issue is when I try to access a function that is in a different Javascript file which is then placed into app.js using Laravel Mix, I have played around with the order of the files which did not make a difference. The only thing that seems to work is have the function in the same file that is calling it, which is what mix should do. I would like to keep them in a separate file so that I can manage them easier in Laravel and custom-queries.js is to be used in multiple apps.

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('./apps/custom-queries');
require('./apps/barcode-gen/user-input');
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', './public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', './public/css');
```

**custom-queries.js**

```
function BarcodesPOSearch(poNumber) {
  console.log('test');
}
```

**user-input.js**

```
$(document).on('click', '#search-by-po-inputs button', function() {
   BarcodesPOSearch($poNumber);
});
```

**Console Error**

```
app.js:32946 Uncaught ReferenceError: BarcodesPOSearch is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (app.js:32946)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (app.js:23180)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (app.js:22988)
```

Comment: Have you made it sure that all required files actually including/loading in the app.js file ?

Comment: I ended up placing the Javascript file into the public folder and using mix just for CSS.